# Where to store Dockerized python application configuration

Tags: python, configuration, docker

Much like data volumne, the configuration for a python app should persist across changes in the app container.  A file in a separate data container?  Database in a separate data container?  I realize there are multiple ways to store the configuration information.  But what patterns are being used in today's Dockerized web apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that will very much depend. It might be useful to distinguish between two types of configuration: the one which define the way the container (application code contained) functions and the one which defines infrastructure (db credentials, collaborators endpoints, etc.).

The functional configuration would more naturally be a part of the image, as often you would like to minimize the variation in the behavior of the resulting containers.

The infrastructure configuration on the other hand has to be specified at the run time for a particular instance (container). The more docker way is to use environmental variables, but at the end it can be anything that suits your needs.